# moving anything on gnome desktop freezes the computer completely

Tags: gnome

-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-12-02 22:17:58 CET, end at Fri 2022-01-14 15:48:52 CET. --
jan 14 15:36:10 beneden02 whoopsie[1438]: [15:36:10] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
jan 14 15:36:10 beneden02 whoopsie[1438]: [15:36:10] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
jan 14 15:36:11 beneden02 whoopsie[1438]: [15:36:11] online
jan 14 15:36:20 beneden02 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
jan 14 15:37:11 beneden02 gnome-shell[3839]: [3833:3833:0114/153711.247752:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source: chrome-extension://mpognobbkildjkofajifpdfhcoklimli/browser.html (0)
jan 14 15:37:11 beneden02 gnome-shell[3839]: [3833:3833:0114/153711.254061:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source: chrome-extension://mpognobbkildjkofajifpdfhcoklimli/main.html (0)
jan 14 15:37:41 beneden02 systemd[1069]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
jan 14 15:37:42 beneden02 dbus-daemon[1112]: [session uid=1000 pid=1112] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.140' (uid=1000 pid=5920 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --window " label="unconfined")
jan 14 15:37:42 beneden02 systemd[1069]: Created slice apps.slice.
jan 14 15:37:42 beneden02 systemd[1069]: Created slice apps-org.gnome.Terminal.slice.
jan 14 15:37:42 beneden02 systemd[1069]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
jan 14 15:37:42 beneden02 dbus-daemon[1112]: [session uid=1000 pid=1112] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
jan 14 15:37:42 beneden02 systemd[1069]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
jan 14 15:37:42 beneden02 systemd[1069]: Started VTE child process 5934 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 5926.
jan 14 15:37:42 beneden02 systemd[1069]: gnome-launched-org.gnome.Terminal.desktop-5917.scope: Succeeded.
jan 14 15:39:01 beneden02 CRON[5980]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
jan 14 15:39:01 beneden02 CRON[5981]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
jan 14 15:39:01 beneden02 CRON[5980]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
jan 14 15:39:04 beneden02 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
jan 14 15:39:04 beneden02 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
jan 14 15:39:04 beneden02 systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
jan 14 15:39:16 beneden02 gnome-shell[3839]: [3833:3833:0114/153916.757335:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source: chrome-extension://mpognobbkildjkofajifpdfhcoklimli/browser.html (0)
jan 14 15:39:16 beneden02 gnome-shell[3839]: [3833:3833:0114/153916.764288:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source: chrome-extension://mpognobbkildjkofajifpdfhcoklimli/main.html (0)
jan 14 15:40:07 beneden02 gnome-shell[3839]: [3833:3833:0114/154007.939789:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source: chrome-extension://mpognobbkildjkofajifpdfhcoklimli/browser.html (0)
jan 14 15:40:07 beneden02 gnome-shell[3839]: [3833:3833:0114/154007.939882:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", source: chrome-extension://mpognobbkildjkofajifpdfhcoklimli/main.html (0)

specs
beneden02
description: Mini PC
product: NUC11PAHi7 (RNUC11PAHi7000)
vendor: Intel(R) Client Systems
version: M15513-303
serial: G6PA12200379
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.3.0 dmi-3.3.0 smp vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=mini family=PA sku=RNUC11PAHi7000 uuid=3449D9A2-3EC8-A784-71BC-1C697AA7B90A
*-core
description: Moederbord
product: NUC11PABi7
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
version: K90104-302
serial: GEPA12000B6U
*-firmware
description: BIOS
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 0
version: PATGL357.0041.2021.0811.1505
date: 08/11/2021
size: 64KiB

```
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 73
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: U3E1
      size: 2006MHz
      capacity: 4700MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 01
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         logical name: /dev/fb0
         version: 01
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
         configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1024x768 visual=truecolor xres=1024 yres=768
         resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:190 memory:603c000000-603cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 6
         bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
         version: 01
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:124 memory:6a500000-6a5fffff
       
    *-network
         description: Wireless interface
         product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
         logical name: wlo1
         version: 20
         serial: a4:6b:b6:27:d0:2b
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
 
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 20
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 20
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:191 memory:603d1a0000-603d1a3fff memory:603d000000-603d0fffff
```

Comment: It might help to see what was in the system logs at the time of the freeze.  After powering the machine up after a freeze, run `journalctl -b -1 -n 25` and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1386817/edit) your question with the results of that command.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to also include the hardware specifications of your system? A brand and model number of the computer would also help identify issues 

Comment: have you tried to run in low graphic mode to test hardware specifications?. you could also really attach needed as @matigo said.